# Searching through a structure based on input

Tags: c++

I was thinking of implementing a little program using a Binary decision diagram. Which Given a binary tree, print its nodes in inorder.
We branch through based on input such as for example in this tree:
The binary tree node has data, pointer to left child
and a pointer to right child

I tried this sort of code but it don't work

```
include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 
  

struct Node 
{ 
    int data; 
    struct Node* left, *right; 
    Node(int data) 
    { 
        this->data = data; 
        left = right = NULL; 
    } 
}; 
  

void printInorder(struct Node* node) 
{ 
  
    printInorder(node->left); 
  
    cout << node->data << " "; 
  
    printInorder(node->right); 
} 


int main() 
{ 
    struct Node *root = new Node(1); 
    root->left             = new Node(2); 
    root->right         = new Node(3); 
    root->left->left     = new Node(4); 
    root->left->right = new Node(5);  
 
  
    cout << "\nInorder traversal of binary tree is \n"; 
    printInorder(root);  
  
  
  
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: `tmp` was never declared in `replace_null()` or you forgot to write it here?

Comment: It might be easier to work from specs rather than from an example. What form must the input take? What does a `0` mean? What is the accepted syntax for specifying a location in the tree? If you write your specs carefully enough, you might find that the code almost writes itself.

Comment: A list of existing packages that implement Binary Decision Diagrams can found at: https://github.com/johnyf/tool_lists/blob/master/bdd.md I would recommend starting with the Python package `dd`: https://github.com/tulip-control/dd (of which I am an author).

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

```
void replace_null(int i, string path, TreeNode* t, string val);
```

The parameter *i* tell us where to move next in the path.

You can call the function like this:

```
    replace_null(0, path, t, val);
```

And now just let the computer have fun following the path:

```
void replace_null(int i, string path, TreeNode* t, string val) {
    if (path[i] == '1') {
       if (t->right == NULL) { // We reached our destination.
          add_tree(t->right, val);
          return; 
       }
       else { // We continue following the path.
          replace_null(i + 1, path, t->right, val); 
       }
    }
    else {
       if (t->left == NULL) { // We reached our destination.
          add_tree(t->left, val);
          return; 
       }
       else { // We continue following the path.
          replace_null(i + 1, path, t->left, val); 
       }
    }
}
```

Note that I did assume the path always reach a NULL node. Otherwise, `if (i == path.size()) return;` :)